# JPA set's id, but entity don't exists

Tags: mysql, spring-data, eclipselink

i'm using JPA (Eclipse-Link), Spring-Data and MySQL. I have a issue with transaction (commit) and id generation. I persist a entity (which contains a detached entity) and after the transaction i would like to use the id. The id is generated, but the entity manager don't find this entity.

Example:
Pojo:

```
private class Assignment {
private final Action action;

private Assignment(final Action action) {
    this.action = action;
}

public Action getAction() {
    return action;
}
```

}

JPA-Entity

```
 @Entity
    public class Action {
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        private ActionType actionType;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        Long id;
    }




@Entity
public class ActionType {
    String name;
}
```

The service:

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class ActionManagement {

    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
    public Assignment assignAction(final ActionType type) {

        entityManager.detach(type);

        Action action = new Action();
        action.setActionType(type);

        action = entityManager.persist(action);
        // id is null, because here is commit or fluh triggerd.
        System.out.println(action.getId());

        return new Assignment(action);

    }
}
```

Unit-Test:

```
public void unitTest(){

    ActionType type = createRandomActionType();

    Assignment assignAction = actionManagement.assignAction(type);
    //ID is NOT null (e.d id:2), but the entity is null
    entityManager.find(Action.class,assignAction.getAction().getId())
}
```

The current issue is, that the action entity has a id, after the transaction, but after a find the entity is always null.

Anybody a idea what is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Turn on JPA logging and check that your transaction has fully committed before your find executes.

Comment: Yes of course, i turned on the JPA logging. Looks fine.

Comment: And is find issuing an SQL query?  Does executing the query return the expected result?  Helps to show us the log too.

Comment: You must remove @Transactional(readOnly = true).